# Amazon SES DKIM signing with Route 53 issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, dkim, amazon-route53, amazon-ses

I had DKIM signing setup and working fine for my example.com for years. But recently i moved my DNS to amazon Route 53 and added all records there, including the CNames that was previously with the original hosting provider. however, since that change i have been getting a notification from Amazon that my DKIM is now pending revocation. But problem is My CNAMES are presented in the Route 53 DNS records including the TXT for the amazonses identifier,

When i check a test email it shows as below, 
[image]

What confuses me is it used to say

```
Signed By: example.com
```

but now it says

```
Signed By: amazonses.com
```

What i am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: You read this, right?  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/easy-dkim-revocation.html

Answer (score 0):

Issue was resolved after 72 hours.  Probably the DNS sync taking the time to inform the DKIM value.